# OnClickListener Error

Tags: android

I am new to Android and tried to run the sample code of the SDK using eclipse. I created the project (via File → New → Project → Android → Android Sample Project), but when I run the project it shows the following error for all the sample projects:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass     method
> - implements android.view.View.OnClickListener.onClick

Then I refered to this forum. Here they mentioned a "compiler compliance level". But my compiler compliance level is on 1.7, and I am using Android 4.0.3 with an API level of 15.

So please help me to rectify this error.

Comment: can you post the lines with the error?

Comment: If an answer has solved your problem, you should click the check mark next to it to accept it, so others (like me) don't type an answer and then realize that your issue has already been solved.  :)  Plus it gives credit to the person that helped you out.

Comment: BTW, I keep hearing that Android doesn't play well with Java 1.7, so we should be using 1.6 as a java compliance level.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that above your OnClick method you have the annotation @Override like so

```
@Override
public void OnClick(View v) {
//Code goes here
}
```

By having @Override, Java knows that you are not creating a new method, in this situation you are letting Java know that you are utilizing that listener.

If you have already done this, check this website http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-solve-must-override-superclass.html

Comment: Lot of thanks. Now i compile the source code without any error.Thank you so much.

Comment: Your welcome.  Remember that if you need anything else, everyone here at stackoverflow will be glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @Override annotation tag.

For some situation. the eclipse can't recognize.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.I fixed it by following change of code

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Use **View**.OnClickListener(){} instead of just OnClickListener(){};

I think this might due to various OnClickListener are there. May be we need to specify which is the relevant one. I would really love to know the real reason if any one knows.